# How to group host from http referer

Tags: php, http-referer

how to group same name but diferent tld.

for example google.com, google.co.id, google.co.jp, etc.

i want to group all of `google.*` as `google`.

here my code to get host from `http referer`.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
    $referal = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    $host_referal = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
}
else {
    $referal = "Unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spitballing here, I didn't consider any fringe cases.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d1d491c7812dc0034b9b354f3285804ba402a48))

```
$referers=['https://google.com','https://www.google.co.id','http://www.google.co.jp'];  // $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
foreach($referers as $referer){
    if(!$referer || !$host=parse_url($referer,PHP_URL_HOST)){  // sometimes $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not delivered
        echo "couldn't parse missing/malformed url";
    }else{
        echo preg_match('~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?\K[^.]+~',$host,$out)?$out[0]:'';
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
google
google
google
```

If this breaks, please offer me the breaking input string so that I can adjust my method.

---

p.s. The truth is, you can probably get away with just calling:

```
$referal=preg_match('~^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?\K[^.]+~',$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],$out)?$out[0]:'Unknown'
```

But there are many posts on StackOverflow that state that this value is not secure, so using `parse_url()` offers a bit more peace of mind.

Comment: what is not secure? http referer?

Comment: That's fine.  Just know that if someone wants to manipulate the data being sent to you, then they can freely do so.  You'll need to sanitize before printing to screen and be sure to use mysqli's prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons or pdo when interacting with the database.  Don't use the old/deprecated `mysql_` functions.